# Pagination React.js with 10 items at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am new to React.js and am trying to implement pagination with React.js with a little filtering. After retrieving data from a server, I don't all the data at once, but up to 10 items. I am not sure what or how to approach it. I read this [documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and wonder if you can implement pagination, but not sure how to do it. Also, is there a way to filter the item by name as in search for the item that starts with the letter "A" for example and use pagination? This is the code that I wrote up until now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import List from './List';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: {
        first: '',
        last: ''
      }
    }

    this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
  }

  getName() {
    axios.get('http://nameserver/people')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          name: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <input placeholder='Search Name' />
        <button onClick={this.getName}>Find</button>
        <List first={this.state.name.first} last={this.state.name.last} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is construct the **string** with the query and then pass it to `axios` and always there is a way to do anything.

Simple example:

```
let query = 'http://nameserver.com/'
query += '/posts?title_like=A'    // you can use RegExp 
query += '?_page=1&_limit=10'
```

Read the doc you posted carefully.